# How to autoclick object tag url using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I want to autoclick the object tag which contents url 
here the sample code

```
<div id="click">
<object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s0.2mdn.net/4496681/Jan-15_BigBuster_468x60.swf" base="http://s0.2mdn.net/4496681" width="468" height="60" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="never" flashvars="clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2Fadclick.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpcs%2Fclick%3Fxai%3DAKAOjstAI9jJ2PokvOzV52zGh3gZCCqMHbnSjbJR4qTwR3qxsWgfCCV7r8A2_0UnTb2NZ4bzb20kOrdONBsLztehawPfbSiISgsDS7sYO2dWejKaXX-9KzwDXqFwWKur0NOACurUM9M%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzDKfrkwsRFCVEAE%26adurl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fadclick.g.doubleclick.net%2Faclk%253Fsa%253DL%2526ai%253DCxbs3k6i7VLOtEoqv-QOKlYKwDP7pr9cDjuz3s2TAjbcBEAEgAGDl6uMDggEXY2EtcHViLTcxNTM4NjcyODYxNDQxNjjIAQmoAwGYBACqBHlP0EjmKaoTSjyZAH1qYgIjH8DgCkUPUBTBelijz9LBfxRZZjVrCXIy6CE3xgC43kRmyYEy-kXMRTqrbcVT_hBUnl94YS9V2TJhmtQoN0UE-E47SmBzb00OGv4eEuAwWE1FGicer1ikRbiirrJjpqWzf2h0kE2DhZRXgAbE-K6ltoyemXmgBiE%2526num%253D1%2526sig%253DAOD64_3e5EMzuFcmQ4Mx7SOvUyqS26tCLA%2526client%253Dca-pub-7153867286144168%2526adurl%253Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.coke2home.com%2Fproducts.php%25253Fcc%25253D30062014_1&amp;moviePath=http://s0.2mdn.net/4496681/&amp;moviepath=http://s0.2mdn.net/4496681/" name="FLASH_200_61_dfa7banner_flash_html_inpage_0" id="FLASH_200_61_dfa7banner_flash_html_inpage_0" allowfullscreeninteractive="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="outline: none;"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by clicking it? Some actions can not be done by issuing click events from javascript. Instead the browser might force the user to generate the click.

Comment: do you want to generate a click inside the flash movie?

Comment: This is not hard to research, what have you tried?

Comment: YES I WANT TO CLICK INSIDE FLASH MOVIE

Comment: YES I WANT TO CLICK INSIDE FLASH MOVIE Axel